# Solving linear congruences - Number Thoery

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am having some trouble getting the correct answer on linear congruences. Any help would be appreciated!

Consider the following:

Solve $25x = 15 $ (mod 29)

The gdc(25,29) = 1. Therefore, x has one solution. Using the extended Euclidean algorithm we know that:

$25x_0 + 29y_0 = 1 $

We get that:

$29 = 25(1) + 4$

$25 = 4(6) + 1$

Therefore:

$1 = 25 - 4(6)$

$1 = 25 - 6(29 - 25)$

$1 = 25(7) + 29(-6)$

Multiplying by 15 we get that

$15 = 25(7*15) + 29(-6*15)$

Now $x_0 = 7*15 = 105$ which is $18$ (mod 29)

I know that my process is wrong because 18 does not satisfy the linear congruence.

Comment: Note $25(18)-15 = 435 = 15(29) \; \to \; 25(18) \equiv 15 \pmod{29}$. Thus, $18$ actually *does* satisfy the congruence equation. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Alternative verification of $(18)$.  $(25) \equiv (-4)$ and $(15) \equiv (44).$  Then $(-4) \times (-11) = (44)$ and $(18) \equiv (-11).$

Comment: Easier: $\bmod 29\!:\ x\equiv \dfrac{15}{25}\equiv \dfrac{44}{-4}\equiv -11\equiv 18\,$ by [twiddling](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) as explained in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving a modular form equations means that you need to find the inverse of the coefficient. In particular here
$$25(7)=29(6)+1$$
$$\Rightarrow 25(7)\equiv 1\quad mod(29)$$
which makes $7$ the multiplicative inverse of $25\quad mod(29)$

and given that $7(15)=29(3)+18$ we get
$$25x\equiv 15\quad mod(29)$$
$$\Rightarrow 7(25x)\equiv =7(15)\quad mod(29)$$
$$\Rightarrow x\equiv 18\quad mod(29)$$

to check
$$25(18)=15(29)+15$$
$$\Rightarrow 25(18)\equiv 15\quad mod(29)$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I have no problem deleting my answer, would you mind coming to chat and explaining what you mean? I am not sure what dupe means

Comment: "dupe" means "duplicate"

Answer (score 0):

Since $\gcd (5,29)=1=\gcd(6,29),$ we have, modulo $29,$ that $25x\equiv 15 \iff$ $ (5)(5x)\equiv (5)(3)\iff$ $ 5x\equiv 3 \iff$ $(6)(5x)\equiv (6)(3)\iff$ $29x+x\equiv 18\iff$ $x\equiv 18.$ Why did I multiply by $6$? Because when you multiply the "$5$" of the "$5x$" by $6$, you get a number that's closer to a multiple of $29$ than $5$ is. For example, modulo $29$, we have $8y\equiv 7\iff$ $32y\equiv 28 \iff$ $3y\equiv -1\iff$ $30y\equiv -10\iff$ $y\equiv -10\equiv 19.$

Comment: $(25)(18)=(100)(18/4)=450=435+15=870/2+15=(29)(30)/2+15=(29)(15)+15.$

Comment: I find it odd, and irritating, that in LaTex we have \gcd but not \lcm. It's hard to remember which one we do have. Also we have \to but not \from.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).